# Enable/Disable Inputs

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am trying to enable and disable set of radio buttons with `prototype`, depending on the other set of radio button selected.

For Ex.
1st Set of radio buttons, labelled 'Wall Skins', they have 4 options
- None
- Red Left
- Red Right
- Red Both

the 2nd set of radio buttons, contains the following options:
- None
- Left
- Right
- Both

if user selects `None` from first set, in the 2nd Set, all the radio button except `None` has to be disabled.

if user selects `Left` from first set, in the 2nd Set, all the radio button except `None` & `Left` has to be disabled.

if user selects `Right` from first set, in the 2nd Set, all the radio button except `None` & `Right` has to be disabled.

if user selects `Both` from first set, in the 2nd Set, all the radio button except `None` & `Both` has to be disabled.

I have written the following script to make this happen, but this doesn't seems to work perfectly, it only disables a single radio button from 2nd Set

```
$('options-skin-dd').select('input[type="radio"]').each(function(element) {
    element.observe('click', disableSkinInstall);
});
```

here `options-skins-dd` is the container that hold the first set of options.

```
function disableSkinInstall(event) {
        var element = Event.element(event);
        var rel = element.readAttribute('rel');
        $('options-skin-installation-labor-dd').select('input[type="radio"]').each(function(element) {
            element.enable();
        });

        if(rel.indexOf("none")!=-1) {
            $('options-skin-installation-dd').select('input[type="radio"]').each(function(element) {
                if(element.readAttribute('title')=="Right" || element.readAttribute('title')=="Both" || element.readAttribute('title')=="Left") {
                    element.disable();
                }
            });
        }
        if(rel.indexOf("-left")!=-1) {
            $('options-skin-installation-dd').select('input[type="radio"]').each(function(element) {
                if(element.readAttribute('title')=="Right" || element.readAttribute('title')=="Both") {
                    element.disable();
                }
            });
        } 
        if(rel.indexOf("-right")!=-1) {
            $('options-skin-installation-dd').select('input[type="radio"]').each(function(element) {
                if(element.readAttribute('title')=="Left" || element.readAttribute('title')=="Both") {
                    element.disable();
                }
            });
        } 
        if(rel.indexOf("-both")!=-1) {
            $('options-skin-installation-dd').select('input[type="radio"]').each(function(element) {

                if(element.readAttribute('title')=="Left" || element.readAttribute('title')=="Right") {
                    element.disable();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I have also tried using `.select()`, but that doesn't seems to work too.

Please let me know, whats going wrong in here.

Comment: You should really use if/else if/else. You can make that code less copy paste happy by using some classes on those elements and selecting them. You could also do it with the title attribute selector too.

Comment: @epascarello I tired the following selector, but this didn't work either `$('options-skin-installation-dd').select('input[type="radio"][title="Left"]', 'input[type="radio"][title="Right"]')`

Comment: Please make example at jsfiddle.net

Comment: I have an improvement for the original observe call `$$('#options-skin-dd input[type="radio"]').invoke("observe","click",disableSkinInstall);` But I would also suggest putting classes on the groups of radio buttons so you can address them as a group using the `$$()` function